# Plone 5 plone.app.ldap install issue

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

Installing plone.app.ldap into Plone 5 produces a formlib error.  The traceback is here: http://pastebin.com/EM9S6UDD

It is a fresh install of Plone 5.0, the only egg pinned to the buildout is plone.app.ldap.

Please advise?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pas.plugins.ldap/ which is newer, has less layers/wrappers and worked in the past better for me. Don't know if this easier to run on Plone 5. Haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I have used it with Plone 5 without problems. Because of many users, I use the performance branches:
- https://github.com/collective/pas.plugins.ldap/tree/performance
- https://github.com/bluedynamics/node.ext.ldap/tree/performance

Answer (score 0):

Plone 5 does not ship with formlib any longer. Try to add zope.formlib to the eggs section in your buildout.

Comment: Actually `five.formlib`, no?

Answer (score 0):

Current version of [plone.app.ldap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.ldap/1.3.2) (1.3.2) is not compatible with Plone 5.

There is some work in progress on [the master branch of the repository](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.ldap); follow up and wait for a new release.

Answer (score 0):

plone.app.ldap simply add a (sometimes broken) UI interface to Plone. Commonly you don't need it if you configure stuff from ZMI.

In that case: just add `Products.PloneLDAP` to your Plone 5 buildout and it will work normally.